# return a certain part of a string

Tags: php, string

If I have a link in a string like: `example.php?this=something&that=somethingelse`

How to I return only what that equals? So: `somethingelse`

I have tried `pregmatch` but haven't gotten it to work. I also don't want to use `substr` because I'm not sure how long `'that'` will be.

To be specific I have

```
user={$md5_id}&activ_code={$activ_code}
```

Being sent to another function, of course I could pass active code as a variable. But I was curious.

Comment: Is there a reliable way to know where the value of `that` ends? Another parameter? A close quote? What is the full string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following...

```
$str = "example.php?this=something&that=somethingelse";
$values = array();
$query = substr(strstr($str, "?"), 1);

parse_str($query, $values);

echo $values["that"];
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use PHP's [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)() function to parse the URL itself, and [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)() function to parse its parameters

Here's an example snippet:

```
$url = "example.php?this=something&that=somethingelse";
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $result);
```

With the above snippet, the result you're after will be inside the `$result['that']` variable

Comment: I did read the original question, and this code can be used to get the parameter the OP wants. I've added some sample code as well

Answer (score 4):

Use [`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/parse_url) (with the `PHP_URL_QUERY` parameter since we only want the query part (after ?) of the URL) and [`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/parse_str) as such:

```
<?php
    $url = "example.php?this=something&that=somethingelse";

    parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $queryParams);

    print_r($queryParams);
    /*
        Array
        (
            [this] => something
            [that] => somethingelse
        )
    */
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/dtQl72Nj)

---

If you only have the string `user={$md5_id}&activ_code={$activ_code}` you can simply use [`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/parse_str):

```
<?php
    $string = "user=ABC123&activ_code=DEF456";

    parse_str($string, $queryParams);

    print_r($queryParams);

    /*
        Array
        (
            [user] => ABC123
            [activ_code] => DEF456
        )
    */
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/QTxd59vh)

Comment: Its more about getting a specific part of a URL that's being passed as a string, but this does infact work for multi purposes if I am correct.

Comment: @Alex Sure does - feel free to play around with the demo provided.

Comment: Just adding a FYI. The question contains a partial URL, but as the docs for parse_url say: Partial URLs are also accepted, parse_url() tries its best to parse them correctly. So parse_url() might break, but I'd trust it more than reinventing your own wheel with substr() or a regex.

Comment: @ErikNedwidek I completely agree - you could always create a regex such as `/\?(.*)$/` but I **do** trust `parse_url` way more. Way smarter heads have been fiddling around with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`substr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [`strstr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) to get the query part of the string (everything after the `?`):

```
$query = substr(strstr($url, '?'), 1)
```

And then use [`parse_str()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to parse the query-string into variables

```
parse_str($query, $vars);
```

The variable you need is now available in the `$vars` array:

```
$that = $vars['that'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full example on how to use [`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/parse_url) and [`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/parse_str).

**Example Code**

```
$url = "http://test.com/example.php?this=something&that=somethingelse";

$url_breakdown = parse_url($url);
parse_str($url_breakdown['query'], $url_params);

print_r($url_breakdown);
print_r($url_params);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => test.com
    [path] => /example.php
    [query] => this=something&that=somethingelse
)
Array
(
    [this] => something
    [that] => somethingelse
)
```

Answer (score 1):

with working preg_match

```
if(preg_match("/^.+that=(.+)&?$/", "example.php?this=something&that=somethingelse", $matches))
    print_r($matches);
```

result

```
Array
(
    [0] => example.php?this=something&that=somethingelse
    [1] => somethingelse
)
```

Comment: I'm not going to downvote as it *does* work - but really? Regex surely isn't the job for this.

Comment: maybe you could be more specific why not?